# What is an alternative to static derived classes which aren't allowed in c#

Tags: c#, class

I have a Pokemon class which is an abstract class. I want to build a bunch of Pokemon which behave similarly. Currently it have the fields: speciesName and health. I have multiple derieved pokemon classes such as Bulbasaur, Venusaur, Charmeleon, etc. Each of these has a different static value for that particular type of Pokemon. I get creating instances of these Pokemon because not all instances of the same type of Pokemon will be exactly the same. They will have different moves, and I can add functionality on such as Nicknames or levels.

```
abstract class Pokemon
    {
        string speciesName;
        int health;
        bool Fainted
        {
            get
            {
                if (health == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        public Pokemon(string speciesName, int health)
        {
            
        }
        public void TakeDamage(int damage)
        {
            health -= damage;
        }
    }
    class Bublasaur :Pokemon
    {
        Move[] possibleMoves = {new Tackle() };
        static int health = 60;
        static string speciesName = "Bublasaur";
        Bublasaur() :base(speciesName, health)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

However, I also have a Move class is abstract and has derived classes which are moves such as Flamethrower and Watergun. They have only static fields.

```
abstract class Move
    {
        int damage;
        string name;
        public Move(int damage, string name)
        {
            this.damage = damage;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    class Tackle :Move
    {
        static int damage = 20;
        static string name = "Tackle";
        public Tackle():base(damage,name)
        {

        }
    }
    class Ember: Move
    {
        static int damage = 30;
        static string name = "Ember";
        public Ember() : base(damage, name)
        {

        }
    }
```

Because I have a base class of Moves, I can't make the class static as static classes can only derive from the object class. However, creating an instance of each move to attach to each Pokemon I create does not seem very intuitive. Is there a way I can implement this better?

Comment: Can you give an example how `Pokemon` is calling the `Move` class? How does it function?

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably make read-only properties named `Damage` and `Name` on the `Move` base-class.  On the sub-classes (like `Tackle`), I'd do it this way: `const int damage = 20;` and `const string name = "Tackle";` and then use those in calling the base class constructor.  A `const` is basically a symbolic name associated with an immutable value.  By leaving the way you have it (with an abstract base class and sub-classes), it allows you to implement customizable behavior in the sub-classes if that's something you decide to do.

Comment: "However, creating an instance of each move to attach to each Pokemon I create does not seem very intuitive." Why do you think so? In fact, I would get rid of your whole inheritance hierarchy for `Move`, and have `Tackle` and `Ember` be `Move` objects, that can be accessed via static properties in the `Move` class. e.g. `Move[] possibleMoves = { Move.Tackle };`

Comment: You might want to take a read through Eric Lippert's [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) posts, in which he discusses the difficulties of modelling a game's logic and rules in C#.

Answer (score 2):

`Tackle` and `Ember` don't extend the behaviour of `Move`, so the inheritance hierarchy seems unneccesary.

You could have a single class `Move` that holds static references to the various instances:

```
class Move
{
    int damage;
    string name;
    private Move(int damage, string name)
    {
        this.damage = damage;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static readonly Move Tackle = new Move(20, "Tackle");
    public static readonly Move Ember = new Move(30, "Ember");
    // Other moves..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move is an action that can be performed by Pokemon.  As such, I think it is better if it is defined as an Interface and that these don't need to be static.

You can then create moves such as Tackle, Ember etc.

public interface IMove
{
public int Damage { get;  }
public string Name { get;  }
}

```
public class Tackle : IMove
{        
    public Tackle()
    {
    }

    //You can still set defaults per class
    public int Damage { get;  } = 30;  
    public string Name { get;  } = "Tackle";
}
```

I don't use a setter, as I assume you don't actually want these values to change after initialisation.  if you do, you can simply add it in.

I would also use an Enum for the Name of the Move (and Pokemon), so that you don't have problems with upper/lower case, spelling mistakes etc.

I would also look at using a Factory to create Pokemons, and maybe even the moves (if you don't already).

I admit to not knowing about the game and characters in Pokemon, so maybe I don';t understand correctly but I don't see why in your Pokemon that Health should be static, as it means all instances of that Pokemon will have the same health level.   Maybe you mean for the Pokemon itself should be a Singleton?